# button2.click выполнить код (button1)

Tags: c#

В первой кнопке прописан код, как можно выполнить этот же код при нажатии второй кнопки. Пробовал такой код

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button4.Click == true)
        {
            button1.Click = button4;
        }

    }
```

ругается что для кнопки нет свойства click

Comment: Ну да, и правда, такого свойства нет. Так что скомпилировать никак не получится. А какую функциональность вы хотите устроить этим кодом?

Comment: И что значит «в кнопке прописан код»?

Comment: Кпопка 1 выполняет расчеты по заданой формуле, для другой кпопки получилася такой же код, и чтобы не писать по новому код для другой кнопки мне нужно просто задать параметр чтобы при нажатии кнопки два выполнялись расчеты из кнопки 1

Comment: Ну, сама по себе кнопка не выполняет расчёты, мы ж тут программисты с вами. Вероятно, у вас есть метод, который подписан обработчиком события нажатия от кнопки №1. Так что вам не составит труда подписать тот же метод на событие нажатия от кнопки №2.

Comment: я как бы только на старте, и еще только учусь. С некоторыми свойствамия языка еще не ознакомлен, но за направление спасибо)

Comment: Ну, посмотрите, как у вас кнопка «соединена» с методом. Когда поймёте, как это работает и в чём магия, остальное будет просто и самоочевидно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите этот код в отдельный метод. И вызывайте этот метод из обоих обработчиков клика.

```
private void CommonMethod()
{
    // здесь нужный код
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod();
}
```

При необходимости, передавайте в этот метод параметры sender и EventArgs.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую)

Comment: Сработало спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Если оба ваши обработчика `Click` делают одно и тоже, то можно привязать один метод к обоим кнопкам сразу:

```
button1.Click += button_Click;
button4.Click += button_Click;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```